# Get the top level directory for an http_archive

Tags: bazel

With bazel 0.23.2 I'm attempting to import my C++ compiler via an http archive, and to do that, I need to find the absolute path for where the compiler is unpacked to find the executables and the include paths (to prevent bazel from complaining about missing dependency declarations).

My top level WORKSPACE looks something like this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(name="gcc-9.2.0", build_file="BUILD.gcc-9.2.0", ...)
```

My BUILD.gcc-9.2.0 file looks something like:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

filegroup(
    name = "toolset",
    srcs = glob(["opt/**"]),
)

sh_binary(
   name = "gcc",
   srcs = ["opt/gcc-9.2.0/bin/gcc"],
)
```

I'd like to use the sh_binary gcc to pass into the starlark for configuring the compiler, but with:

```
gcc_toolchain_config(
   name = "gcc_9_2_0_config",
   root = "$(location @gcc-9.2.0//:gcc)"
)
```

I get the error:

```
invalid label '$(location @gcc-9.2.0//:gcc)' in attribute 'root' in 'gcc_toolchain_config' rule: invalid target name '$(location @gcc-9.2.0//:gcc)': target names may not contain '//' path separators
```

If I just try to pass in the label, without the location, using

```
gcc_toolchain_config(
   name = "gcc_9_2_0_config",
   root = "@gcc-9.2.0//:gcc"
)
```

I get a dependency chain error:

```
> @bazel_tools//tools/launcher:launcher (host)
|   @bazel_tools//src/tools/launcher:launcher (host)
|   @bazel_tools//src/tools/launcher:bash_launcher (host)
|   @bazel_tools//src/tools/launcher:launcher_base (host)
|   @bazel_tools//src/tools/launcher/util:util (host)
|   //source/compilers:gcc_9_2_0 (host)
|   //source/compilers:cc-compiler-gcc_9_2_0 (host)
|   //source/compilers:gcc_9_2_0_config (host)
|   @gcc-9.2.0//:gcc (host)
`-- @bazel_tools//tools/launcher:launcher (host)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, but each of the paths in the toolchain's configuration has a different way to get that information without every expanding the path. If you expand the path, the action would be different on every machine, which makes remote caching impossible, so bazel has a variety of ways to avoid it. I think there are only three categories:

[`tool_path.path`s](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html#tool) should be specified relative to the package where your toolchain lives. I think that means just `"gcc"` for your example, although I'm not sure what `gcc_toolchain_config` does so maybe not.

`cxx_builtin_include_directory`s can use a special syntax which looks like `%package(@gcc-9.2.0//usr/include)%/c++`. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation about that anywhere besides [my commit adding it](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/4d035ddd28cd4c31506bae26d9877d5012c31495)...

Other paths (in `flags` etc) should be specified relative to the execroot, which will be the working directory for all the actions being run. This means they look like `--sysroot=external/gcc-9.2.0/usr`.